# wkhtmltopdf gives error when executed with apache user

Tags: php, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, shell-exec

I'm trying to execute `wkhtmltopdf` with the apache user using shell_exec.
When i run `wkhtmltopdf file.html file.pdf` from terminal everything works, but when I run it with with the apache user using

```php
echo shell_exec("wkhtmltopdf file.html file.pdf 2>&1");
```

it prints these messages:

```
wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by wkhtmltopdf) 
wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by wkhtmltopdf)
wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebKit.so.5)
wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebKit.so.5)
wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebKit.so.5)
wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Svg.so.5)
wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5PrintSupport.so.5)
wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5)
wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5)
wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XmlPatterns.so.5)
wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5)
wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5)
wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5)
wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5)
wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5)
wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebChannel.so.5)
wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.63)
wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Positioning.so.5)
wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Positioning.so.5)
wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Positioning.so.5)
wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.63)
wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Sensors.so.5)
wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwoff2dec.so.1.0.2)
wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwoff2dec.so.1.0.2)
wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5)
wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5)
```

Comment: Could you provide more information about your OS? If I am not mistaken, this problem appears in **libstdc++.so.6** and is solved in **libstdc++.so.6.0.24**. You could upgrade the version of *libstdc++* and see if it solves your problem

Comment: I solved adding ```daemon ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL``` to ```/etc/sudoers```file and adding ```sudo``` before the command. I know this is a workaround, so I would like solve this problem in a better way (I don't want to give to apache user all the privileges of root user)
By the way, ```uname -a```prints the following text: ```Linux debian 4.19.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2 (2020-04-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux```