# wkhtmltopdf on apache server / linux (Fedora 34) generation error

Tags: php, linux, apache, fedora, wkhtmltopdf

when using wkhtmltopdf from normal terminal everything works fine, but when I use it from apache2 localhost server it generates the following error:

```
/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf) /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /lib64/libwkhtmltox.so.0) /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

so I know that there is some issue with the libstdc++ library and some messed up library versions, but I have no idea how to fix this. can anybode help me?

I already tried to add this to my /etc/sudoers file as suggested here:
[wkhtmltopdf gives error when executed with apache user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65439528/wkhtmltopdf-gives-error-when-executed-with-apache-user)

but unfortunately this didn't help.

Update: I was curious if the correct version of the library was installed, so I ran this command:

```
strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep CXXABI
```

which gave me this output:

```
CXXABI_1.3
CXXABI_1.3.1
CXXABI_1.3.2
CXXABI_1.3.3
CXXABI_1.3.4
CXXABI_1.3.5
CXXABI_1.3.6
CXXABI_1.3.7
CXXABI_1.3.8
CXXABI_1.3.9
CXXABI_1.3.10
CXXABI_1.3.11
CXXABI_1.3.12
CXXABI_1.3.13
CXXABI_TM_1
CXXABI_FLOAT128
```

so the needed version seems to be installed

this is the PHP Code I use:

```
$cmd = '/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf www.google.de google.pdf'; 

$ret = shell_exec($cmd.' 2>&1'); 

var_dump($ret);
```

Update: I tried to search the libstdc++.so.6 file in /opt/lampp/lib/ and found out that here there is a libstdc++.so.6 and libstdc++.so.6.0.19 file, I think I would have to update this to 6.0.24, does anyone know how to do this? (I tried to copy the file into this lib folder but no success)

Comment: You might want to include a code snippet of your PHP code that you use to call the wkhtmltopdf executable.

Comment: @Sil will include it

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution which works for me (I don't know why it works, because usually wkhtmltopdf doesn't require super user rights when I run it from terminal, however adding sudo in front of the command worked for me)

```
$cmd = 'sudo /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf www.google.de google.pdf'; 

$ret = shell_exec($cmd.' 2>&1'); 

var_dump($ret);
```