# The shell_exec and exec() commands don't work on linux Ubuntu in my localhost Ububtu 20.04

Tags: php, shell, localhost, exec, wkhtmltopdf

The following code only works in my Terminal but it doesn't work in my localhost xampp linux Unbuntu 20.04, Both shell_exec() and exec() don't work. When I go to localhot it executes all the code but not its two functions. The following code does not execute.

```
// Add the --enable-local-file-access option to enable access to local files (HTML)
$wkhtmltopdfCommand = "wkhtmltopdf --enable-local-file-access {$outputHtmlPath} {$pdfOutputPath}";
shell_exec($wkhtmltopdfCommand);
```

I don't know if I need to change anything for this to work, but I need some advice.

Comment: What errors are you getting when executing through localhost? Is anything after the shell_exec command executed? What does the return value of shell_exec look like?

Comment: @volkerschulz I tried to add this 
```error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$wkhtmltopdfCommand = "/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf --enable-local-file-access journal.html journal-new.pdf";
exec($wkhtmltopdfCommand);```

That I can see the errors but no error appeared. What should I do?

Comment: I've replied with an answer below so I can better format the code needed to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1) Check the security setup

Can `shell_exec()` be run or not? If it can't then it's because
you are having some security settings enabled.

The problem is that `shell_exec()` and `exec()` can be disabled
for security reasons. This can be changed by editing
[PHP's *disable_functions* option](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions).

INI settings are usually stored in specific `*.ini` files under the
`/etc/php/*` directories. So you have to look for some settings
in there. You’ll find several INI settings, depending on how *PHP* is
run. To find them :

```bash
find /etc/php/ -iname 'php.ini'
```

This could output something like this :

```
/etc/php/8.2/fpm/php.ini
/etc/php/8.2/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php/8.2/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/8.2/cgi/php.ini
```

To see the settings and which INI file is loaded, add this at the
beginning of your script and call it via your web server :

```php
phpinfo();
die();
```

You'll see all the loaded INI files and what is set on the
`disable_functions` option.

`/etc/php/8.2/cli/php.ini` is probably setting `disable_functions`
to an empty string, meaning that in command line there's no
restriction. But for the other INI files, this option might contain
a list of functions that you won't be able to run. Edit this option
if needed. But be always aware that giving your server the ability
to run some binaries can lead to some security issues if your app
is taking some user input to build the command.

[*Apache* configuration can also set some
PHP settings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php),
just for a specific Virtual Host. So have a look at them if you can't
find something in the `php.ini` files.

Depending on your PHP setup, you may also have to check
[safe_mode](http://php.adamharvey.name/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php)
and
[suhosin.executor.*](https://suhosin5.suhosin.org/stories/configuration.html#executor-options) if you have the *Suhosin* hardening module installed.

#### 2) Verify that you can run `shell_exec`

There are several ways to run a binary.
[`shell_exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)
is equivalent to the built-in
[backtick operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php).
So if `shell_exec` is listed in the `disable_functions` option then
you won't be able to use the backtick operator.

If you get an error 500 then it's typically because you cannot run
`shell_exec`. If you check `/var/log/nginx/error.log` or
`/var/log/apache2/error.log` with this command :

```bash
sudo tail -f /var/log/{apache2,nginx}/error.log
```

It will print both logs until you press
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
You may see this error :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function shell_exec()
```

*PHP* also offers
[`exec()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php),
[`passthru()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php),
[`system()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php),
and the
[`proc_*()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php)
functions. So you've got several possibilities to try and run your
command.

Have a try with a simple *PHP* code :

```php
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

echo 'PHP user given with the "id" command: ' . `id`; // equivalent to shell_exec('id');
echo 'System date is ' . `date --iso-8601=seconds`;
```

This should output RAW text in your browser with :

```
PHP user given with the "id" command: uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)
System date is 2023-09-29T11:50:28+00:00
```

#### 3) Use a full path to the binary

When `shell_exec()` is run from the web server, it's rather common
that the binary isn't found in the `PATH`.
Usually, the `www-data` user running *PHP* won't even have a shell.
But this user can normally run some binaries, except if some settings
at point 1 is blocking it.

To find the full path to a binary, use the `which` command :

```bash
which wkhtmltopdf
```

This should output the full path to the binary. Certainly something
such as `/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf`.

Now replace your PHP code with the full path to the binary:

```php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
echo shell_exec('/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf --version');
```

Does it print `wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6` like expected?

If no, then we have to investigate more at the next point.

#### 4) Get the execution output and find errors

This can be done with the help of `exec()`, `passthru()` or `system()`
as they all return the execution status code.

With the proposition of
[Volkerschulz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22629028), we'll also
redirect the standard error stream to the standard output stream so
that we can see some details that may have only be printed to the
error stream.

This is done by redirecting *stderr* (`2`) into *stdout* (`1`) by adding  `2>&1` after your command.
Just as info, *stdin* is `0`.

In *PHP*, this becomes :

```php
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$command = '/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf --wrong-option 2>&1';

$last_line = exec(
  $command,    // The command to execute.
  $output,     // A variable that will be filled with an array of all the lines returned.
  $result_code // The return status of the executed command.
);

var_export([
  '$command' => $command,
  '$output' => $output,
  '$last_line' => $last_line,
  '$result_code' => $result_code,
]);
```

This outputs :

```
array (
  '$command' => '/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf --wrong-option 2>&1',
  '$output' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Unknown long argument --wrong-option',
    1 => '',
    2 => 'Name:',
    3 => '  wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6',
    ...
    ...
    95 => '',
  ),
  '$last_line' => '',
  '$result_code' => 1,
)
```

Now I'm able to see that I got a `$result_code` of 1 instead of 0.

In case the executable is having other errors, you'll see them in
the `$output` array as the *stderr* stream should be visible. This
should help you find how to fix the issue. Probably some other
security problems due to the fact the `www-data` user might be
missing some rights, paths or whatever.

PS: On my *Vagrant* box of *Ubuntu 22.04*, I managed to run *wkhtmltopdf* without errors on both *Apache* and *NGINX*.

Don't forget also that your `www-data` user should have write
access to the destination folder where you are producing the PDF file.

#### 5) Try re-installing *wkhtmltopdf* and/or use a PHP wrapper

You might have to re-install *wkhtmltopdf* if it's not properly
working :

```bash
sudo apt remove wkhtmltopdf
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install wkhtmltopdf
```

You can also try using a *PHP* wrapper library for *wkhtmltopdf*
called [Snappy](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy). It might be
useful.

#### 6) Switch to an alternative in pure PHP if necessary

Perhaps you won't manage to make `wkhtmltopdf` work that easily.
It's a pity as it's effectively a fast and reliable solution.

But to create a *PDF* from *HTML* you could also use the
[Dompdf PHP library](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf). I've used
it in the past and was happy with it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. But neither of your options worked. My php.ini file is here ``/etc/php/8.2/cli/php.ini`` but I don't know how I can use the ``disable_functions`` function to activate its two functions. Can you tell me more and either more from A to Z? And the two options don't work. Please tell me more so that I can make it work properly?

Comment: `/etc/php/8.2/cli/php.ini` is for the command line interface (CLI) and this is what is already working. So it’s not this INI file that you have to edit. Did the `phpinfo()` call show you in the web page what is set to `disable_functions`? It should also have shown you which INI file is loaded. You could also do a recursive search under `/etc/php/8.2/` to see which files contains these settings. And what does the log show? What does `shell_exec()` return? First try a simple `shell_exec('ls -al')` to see if it lists the current directory. Advance step by step to investigate where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
shell_exec($wkhtmltopdfCommand);
```

try

```
$result = passthru($wkhtmltopdfCommand . ' 2>&1');
var_dump($result);
```

and it should tell you what's wrong.

Comment: I've run the code and it returns this:
```/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf) /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf:```

What should I do?

Comment: This means, the php (apache) user (in Ubuntu that's most likely www-data) has insufficient rights to access the dependencies. To verify that, try the (unsafe!) solution from the second comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65439528/wkhtmltopdf-gives-error-when-executed-with-apache-user

Comment: This link didn't really help me. What can I do?

Comment: @JuniorOge You could also try to replace your use of *wkhtmltopdf* by the use of the [Dompdf library](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) which will not use shell commands to do the operation. This will be safer than giving root privileges to your *Apache* configuration.

Comment: I agree with @PatrickJanser - allowing www-data to sudo w/out password is definitely for troubleshooting only. Did you try the suggestions from the comments mentioned above? What was the outcome?

Comment: @PatrickJanser I upvoted your answer. Would you mind to add my answer to yours (as a 3rd bullet point) so it becomes the most complete "trouble shooting guide" for others having a similar problem?

Comment: @volkerschulz Oh, thanks! Great idea! I'll do that in a moment. I'll quickly run a *Vagrant* box with *Ubuntu 22.04* so that we have a similar config. I'll also add this to my personal doc, as it can be handy, as you say :-)